# Avoid ORM to return Cake\I18n\Time instance

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have the following data on my db

```sql
  DATE           DATE         TIME
+--------------+------------+----------------+
| initial_date | final_date | expected_hours |
+--------------+------------+----------------+
| 2015-04-20   | 2015-05-24 | 13:00:00       |
| 2015-04-13   | 2015-05-17 | 13:00:00       |
+--------------+------------+----------------+
```

but when I call

```php
$this->set('weeks', $this->paginate($this->Weeks));
```

it returns me `Cake\I18n\Time` instance on those 3 columns, as it says [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/time.html)

**How can I avoid this instance?**

**EDIT:**

The reason I want to do that is because when I have something like `44:00:00`on `expected_hours` it fails with

```php
DateTime::modify(): Failed to parse time string (44:00:00) at position 0 (4): Un
expected character
```

This accepts only `24:00:00` or less...

**Any ideas are welcome**

Comment: What is the reason you don't want the objects?

Comment: updated the question with the reason

Answer (score 2):

In your `WeeksTable` class add this:

```php
use Cake\Database\Schema\Table as Schema;

...
protected function _initializeSchema(Schema $schema)
{
    $schema->columnType('initial_date', 'string');
    $schema->columnType('final_date', 'string');
    $schema->columnType('expected_hours', 'string');

    return $schema;
}
```

That will force the schema system to treat those columns as just strings.

Comment: I did that and it throws me `Declaration of App\Model\Table\WeeksTable::_initializeSchema() should be compatible with Cake\ORM\Table::_initializeSchema(Cake\Database\Schema\Table $table)`

Comment: ok I fixed that and fixed your answer aswell... but the problem is still there, the `initial_date` and `final_date` works properly but when I added the `expected_hours` to string the server gives me a `503` error